# Как выбрать главный раздел для товара

Tags: битрикс

Каждому товару можно присвоить несколько мест в каталоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в хлебных крошках отображается только один вид расположения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы навигационная строка для этого товара шла через видеопроекторы?

Здесь: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic96655/ рекомендуется задать "поле BLOCK_SECTION_ID", но я не могу найти в администрировании, где же это поле задаётся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вначале, если на вкладке "Элемент" товара отсутствует поле ввода "Основной раздел", добавляем его через настройки (шестерёнка в правом верхнем углу):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И потом, в этом поле ввода выбираем раздел, от которого мы хотим отображать хлебные крошки на странице товара:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]